# Xamarin.Forms "Preserve Vector Data" in asset catalog

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to activate Asset Catalogs with PDF-backed vector images and "Preserve Vector Data" in Visual Studio (Xamarin.iOS project)?

Like in Xcode 9: [image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?